# C# selenium: How to force quit the further step definitions in my specflow scenario

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Can you please tell me how to force quit the further step definitions in my specflow scenario.

I'm trying with webDriver.Close() and webDriver.Quit()

Although the web browser is closing i do see that the next definitions in my specflow are getting executed.

Comment: The SpecFlow scenario's are just steps of your tests. You can use Selenium Webdriver to do actions from your tests but closing Selenium will not stop your SpecFlow tests. 
Why do you want the scenario to quit?

Comment: Could you please add some example code and what you expect to happen

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow scenarios are like unit tests. If you want to quit them, because of an error, make an assertation or throw an exception.